# jquery ajax load all filename from folder

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Hello guys can someone please show me the right way to get all the file names from a folder? I dont know how to get there and collect it. It dont find any files in the data with a:contains(".csv") because it is not returning any console logs. but there are 3 csv files in the folder.

here is the script which i use in my html in a script tag:

```
var folder = "csvData/";
    var fileextension = ".csv";
    $.ajax({
    url: folders
    , success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
            console.log(filename);
        });
    }
});
```

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzUMB.png)

Comment: You need to use any web server like tomcat or php with ajax

Comment: @DilipGodhani but there is data in the variable data. when i do console.log(data) it displays a html with my file names in it. i just dont know how to get the file names out of there

Comment: share that data its displaying in logs, so i can help you out